# get name and controller name of partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with mvc and need to do the following. From within a partial view, how can I dynamically find what its name is and also the name of the folder it exists in?

I was doing it by the controller and action name but this does not give the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Using Razor..

```
@Html.Label(Request.RawUrl) //Action

@Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath)) //View Name
```

Comment: Thanks for this - any performance implications of regularly calling Path.GetFileName?

Comment: `Path.GetFileName` simply parses path and returns file name. Maybe `Server.MapPath` is the problem here. You should try...